# sklearn ridgeCV versus ElasticNetCV

Tags: python, lasso-regression

When setting `l1_ratio = 0`, the elastic net reduces to Ridge regression.
However, I am unable to match the results obtained from sklearn's `ridgeCV` versus `ElasticNetCV`. They appear to produce very different optimal alpha values:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNetCV, RidgeCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#data generation
np.random.seed(123)
beta = 0.35
N = 120
p = 30

X = np.random.normal(1, 2, (N, p))
y = np.random.normal(5, size=N) + beta * X[:, 0]
#lambdas to try:
l = np.exp(np.linspace(-2, 8, 80))

ridge1 = RidgeCV(alphas = l, store_cv_values=True).fit(X, y)
MSE_cv = np.mean(ridge1.cv_values_, axis =0)#.shape
y_pred = ridge1.predict(X=X)
MSE = mean_squared_error(y_true=y,y_pred=y_pred)

print(f"best alpha: {np.round(ridge1.alpha_,3)}")
print(f"MSE: {np.round(MSE,3)}")
```

which yields
**best alpha: 305.368**,
*MSE: 0.952*

While `ElasticNetCV` ends up with a similar MSE, its penalty parameters seem to be on a different scale (actually agreeing with the R implementation)

```
ridge2 = ElasticNetCV(cv=10, alphas = l, random_state=0, l1_ratio=0);
ridge2.fit(X, y) 
y_pred = ridge2.predict(X=X)
MSE = mean_squared_error(y_true=y,y_pred=y_pred)

print(f"best alpha: {np.round(ridge2.alpha_,3)}")
print(f"MSE: {np.round(MSE,3)}")
```

yielding
**best alpha: 2.192**,
*MSE: 0.934*

Are the penalties defined differently ?
Does one maybe divide by N ?
Or is it due to the very different cross validation strategies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the penalties defined differently? Does one maybe divide by N?

Yes, that's the cause of the discrepancy. In elastic-net the regularisation part of the [cost function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#elastic-net) is scaled by the number of samples relative to the error term. This is not the case for [RidgeCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#regression). Therefore, to make the cost functions equivalent, we'd need to divide the `ElasticNetCV` alphas by the size of the training fold.

> Is it due to the very different cross validation strategies?

`RidgeCV` uses an internal efficient LOO scheme. We can control for the CV scheme by setting `cv=LeaveOneOut()` in `ElasticNetCV` - this means both models would be using LOO. `ElasticNetCV` would otherwise default to 5-fold CV.

When using `cv=LeaveOneOut()` with `ElasticNet`, the training fold size is `n_samples-1`, so that's what we need to scale by.

Unlike `RidgeCV`, `ElasticNetCV` doesn't retain the CV scores for each alpha. I added a 'manual' version of `ElasticNetCV` where I combined `ElasticNet` with `GridSearchCV` using LOO, which gave me access to the MSE for each alpha (for comparison with `RidgeCV`).

After applying the requisite scaling, the results line up:

```py
RidgeCV
  best alpha: 305.368 <---
  MSE: 0.952
  Effective dof (using n_samples - 1): 18.21

ElasticNetCV using LOO
  best alpha | scaled: 2.566 | scaled: 305.368 <---
  MSE: 0.953
  Effective dof (using n_samples): 18.16

ElasticNet + GridSearchCV using LOO
  best alpha | scaled: 2.566 | unscaled: 305.368 <---
  MSE: 0.953
  Effective dof (using n_samples): 18.16
```

[image]

The calculation of effective dof is my best guess at how it's done, referencing the supplied links (see comments in code).

According to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-cross-validation-estimator, `RidgeCV` with LOO CV, unlike other CV estimators, does not refit on the *entire* dataset (but rather refits on `n_samples-1` due to LOO). This is why its effective dof is slightly different from the other estimators that do refit on the entire dataset (`n_samples`).

> **cross-validation estimator**
> An estimator that has built-in cross-validation capabilities to automatically select the best hyper-parameters [...] By default, all these estimators, *apart from RidgeCV with an LOO-CV*, will be refitted on the *full* training dataset after finding the best combination of hyper-parameters.

---

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNetCV, RidgeCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

#data generation
np.random.seed(123)
beta = 0.35
N = 120
p = 30

X = np.random.normal(1, 2, (N, p))
y = np.random.normal(5, size=N) + beta * X[:, 0]

#lambdas to try:
alphas = np.exp(np.linspace(-2, 8, 80))
#
# RidgeCV with internal efficient LOO CV
#
ridge1 = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, store_cv_values=True).fit(X, y)
MSE_cv = np.mean(ridge1.cv_values_, axis=0)#.shape
y_pred = ridge1.predict(X=X)
MSE = mean_squared_error(y_true=y,y_pred=y_pred)

print('RidgeCV')
print("  best alpha:", round(ridge1.alpha_, 3), '<---')
print("  MSE:", round(MSE, 3))

#My understanding of how to calculate the effective dof
# H_ridge = X⋅(X'⋅X +λ⋅I)**-1 ⋅ X'
#  https://tommasorigon.github.io/datamining/slides/un_C.html#shrinkage-effect-of-ridge-regression-i
#
#Effective dof = 1 + tr(H_ridge)
# https://tommasorigon.github.io/datamining/slides/un_C.html#effective-degrees-of-freedom-ii

#According to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-cross-validation-estimator
# RidgeCV with LOO CV, unlike other CV estimators, does not refit on the *entire* dataset
# (but rather refits on n_samples-1 due to LOO). This is why its effective dof
# is marginally different from the other estimators below that do refit on the
# entire dataset (n_samples).
H_ridge1 = X @ np.linalg.pinv(X.T @ X + ridge1.alpha_ * np.eye(p)) @ X.T
print('  Effective dof (using n_samples - 1):', 1 + H_ridge1.trace().round(2))

#
# ElasticNetCV with LOO CV
#
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

fold_size = len(X) - 1
alphas_scaled = alphas / fold_size #for equivalent cost func to RidgeCV

ridge2 = ElasticNetCV(
    cv=LeaveOneOut(), alphas = alphas_scaled,
    l1_ratio=1e-10, random_state=0
)
ridge2.fit(X, y)
y_pred = ridge2.predict(X=X)
MSE = mean_squared_error(y_true=y, y_pred=y_pred)

print('\nElasticNetCV using LOO')
print(
    '  best alpha | scaled:', round(ridge2.alpha_, 3),
    '| scaled:', round(ridge2.alpha_ * fold_size, 3), '<---'
)
print("  MSE:", round(MSE, 3))

#See H_ridge1 calculation for references
lambda2 = ridge2.alpha_ * len(X)
H_ridge2 = X @ np.linalg.pinv(X.T @ X + lambda2 * np.eye(p)) @ X.T
print('  Effective dof (using n_samples):', 1 + H_ridge2.trace().round(2))

#
# "Manual" version of ElasticNetCV
# i.e. ElasticNet + GridSearchCV using LOO
# Used for getting CV score for each alpha
#
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

search = GridSearchCV(
    ElasticNet(l1_ratio=1e-10),
    param_grid=dict(alpha=list( alphas / fold_size )),
    scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
    cv=LeaveOneOut(),
    n_jobs=-1
).fit(X, y)

ridge3 = search.best_estimator_
y_pred = ridge3.predict(X)
MSE = mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)

print('\nElasticNet + GridSearchCV using LOO')
print(
    "  best alpha | scaled:", round(ridge3.alpha, 3),
    "| unscaled:", round(ridge3.alpha * fold_size, 3), '<---'
)
print("  MSE:", round(MSE, 3))

#See H_ridge1 calculation for references
lambda3 = ridge3.alpha * len(X)
H_ridge3 = X @ np.linalg.pinv(X.T @ X + lambda3 * np.eye(p)) @ X.T
print('  Effective dof (using n_samples):', 1 + H_ridge3.trace().round(2))

#
# Plot CV scores vs alpha
#
plt.scatter(
    alphas, ridge1.cv_values_.mean(axis=0),
    color='black', marker='s', s=50, label='RidgeCV'
)
plt.scatter(
    alphas, -search.cv_results_['mean_test_score'],
    color='gray', marker='.', label=r'ElasticNet(L1$\approx$0) + LOO CV'
)
plt.legend(fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha$')
plt.ylabel('CV MSE')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 3)

#Extra formatting
[plt.gca().spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['right', 'top']]
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_bounds(0, 3000)
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_bounds(1.35, 1.5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a fantastically thorough answer !

Comment: This scaling is also very important if one wants to compute the effective degrees of freedom for Ridge ! Might you have an example in sklearn ?

Comment: This page outlines the cost function used for different linear models in `sklearn`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html Scrolling down to the Ridge section for example, the equation shows how the regularisation part is multiplied by *alpha* compared to the data part of the formula. Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: Thx again! I meant the computation of the effective dof via the hat matrix as outlined here: https://tommasorigon.github.io/datamining/slides/un_C.html#ridge-regression
Clearly, one has to plug in the "correctly scaled" lambda into the equation.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure about this from an analytical perspective (asking on CrossValidated is an option if you needed a more rigorous answer). My hunch is that since, for this special case (L1=0), the ridge and EN cost functions are equivalent when using `alpha_en=alpha_ridge / fold_size`, then we'd use `lambda_ridge=ridge1.alpha_` and `lambda_en=ridge2.alpha_ * fold_size` (because `ridge2.alpha_` returns the scaled-down alphas we originally supplied it with). I get `dof=18.2`.

Comment: Thx again! Would you mind sharing your dof code ? I get different numbers. Mine would be 
`_, S, _ = np.linalg.svd(X_scaled)` `df3a = np.sum(np.square(S) / (np.square(S) + ridge3.alpha * fold_size))`

Comment: No problem. I have updated my answer to include how I think the dof is calculated, and an explanation as to why the results differ slightly between `RidgeCV` and others. I have referenced the formulas in the code comments, where I refer back to the notes you linked earlier.

Comment: Thanks a ton again (too bad I can upvote this answer only once!). Your way of computing the dof is actually identical to the svd way. The only difference is that I scaled X to mean zero and sd 1.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it's helpful. I used `1 + trace(H)`, whereas the SVD method returned the same value as `trace(H)`. That's why I get 18 rather than 17. My understanding is that it comes down to inclusion of the intercept. PS. I think we'd multiply by `N` rather than `fold_size` in the SVD formula you posted above, because `ridge3` re-fits the model on the entirety of the data (`N` samples) rather than just a split of the data (`fold_size` samples). The difference is marginal though, as `fold_size` and `N` differ only by 1 when using LOO CV.